# AppCompat theme not applied to TextView android:autoLink="phone"

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat

I'm converting an app from Holo theme to AppCompat Material Design using the AppCompat v23 library.  I have a TextView with `android:autoLink="phone"` so the user can tap on the TextView to initiate a call to the displayed phone number in the TextView.

When I go to the activity on a Lollipop phone I notice the hyperlink is using the default material grade color instead of using colors from my theme. Is it possible to theme the color of the TextView with `android:autoLink="phone"` applied?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    tools:text="(904) 867-5309" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never use Xamarin, but I think that the logic is the same with native android. You can add on your `TextView` the line `android:textColorLink="yourcolorhere"` and the color will change

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything.